# Programmatically set default applications in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, dconf, gsettings

I want to set Chromium as my default web browser in Gnome.

I could use the GUI (Settings → Details → Default Applications), but I much prefer to script such customizations using `gsettings` or similar cli tools.

As far as I can tell there's no setting for this in `gsettings` or `dconf`. Can it be done? Where does Gnome store these settings?

Answer (score 4):

For 18.04, this works

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

`update-alternatives` sets the default browser for the soft links `x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser`.  But these soft links seem no longer used by the system by default.

It looks none of these is stored in the dconf system.

Comment: Regarding the `dconf` and `gsettings` comments, it seems that the information about the default browser is stored only in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list`.